# How to pass params to an event handler within map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two initial state:

```
element_array: [],
element_items: {
  element_type: "",
  element_name: ""
},
```

The form takes a input and updates state of `element_items`, then from there I concat `element_items` into `element_array` using:

```
const currentTypeElement = this.state.element_items
this.setState(function (currentState) {
  return {
    element_array: currentState.element_array.concat([currentTypeElement])
  }
});
```

This works fine as I can map `element_array` in a table. But I also want to add a 'Edit' button in the table row for each `element_array` object. So I added a function in my component:

```
handleElementEdit(prop) {
  ...
}
```

In my `render()` method I have

```
<table className="mb-0 table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Element Type</th>
      <th>Element Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {this.state.element_array.map(function (prop, key) {
      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          <td>{prop.element_type}</td>
          <td>{prop.element_name}</td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleElementEdit(prop)}>Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )}
    )}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I click button It shows an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleElementEdit' of undefined.

`onClick` event should pass prop to `handleElementEdit` function.

I don't understand why this is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically what happened in your case when you use the map function the scope of `this` is limited to that map function and `this.handleElementEdit` will try to find the function in `map` and because of it, it will throw the error.

You can use the arrow functions for it like.

```
{this.state.element_array.map((prop, key)=> {
    return (
        <tr key={key}>
           <td>{prop.element_type}</td>
           <td>{prop.element_name}</td>
           <td>
               <button onClick={() => this.handleElementEdit(prop)}>
               Edit
               </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
     )
   })}
```

Arrow function will use to retain the scope of your parent class.

Another solution is, You can bind your event handler in the constructor like:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleElementEdit = this.handleElementEdit.bind(this);
  }
```

Also you can use the below mentioned solution, like store the `this` scope in variable and use that variable to bind the event.

```
 let that=this;
  {this.state.element_array.map(function (prop, key)=> {
        return (
            <tr key={key}>
               <td>{prop.element_type}</td>
               <td>{prop.element_name}</td>
               <td>
                   <button onClick={() => that.handleElementEdit(prop)}>
                   Edit
                   </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
         )
       })}
```

Comment: thanks bro it worked. can you explain why do I have to use arrow function instead of anonymous function. What's the difference. Thanks